# Windows Embedded Standard 2009 XPECMD.wsf script fails; "cannot create object named CMI.CMI"

Tags: windows-embedded-standard

I'm trying to build a Windows Embedded Standard 2009 image, following a process written for creating an XP Embedded SP2 image with adjustments where necessary. When executing the `XPECMD.wsf` script (`c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded\bin\xpecmd.wsf`) using the `cscript` command, I get the following error:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Embedded\bin\xpecmd.wsf(3405, 15) WScript.CreateObject: Could not create object named "CMI.CMI".
```

CMI is the Component Manager Interface, and the XPECMD.wsf script that contains that line is, I think, delivered with the Windows Embedded Std 2009 tools, so I don't think the problem is that Win Embedded Std obsoleted it. **EDIT:** In fact, apparently the whole point of XPECMD is to provide a scriptable interface to the CMI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940741(v=winembedded.5).aspx

I have no idea what's causing this, I don't see any similar errors in google searches or elsewhere, and I don't even really know if this is an appropriate StackOverflow question, but I'm mystified, so if anyone can offer some suggestions, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79c59599-373d-4062-9900-55477429e759/help-error-component-manager-interface-cmi

The `XPECMD` script *must* be run with the 32-bit version of `cscript.exe`, which is found in `%windir%\SysWoW64` rather than `%windir%\system32`. This can be done either by using the WoW64 version of `cmd.exe` to launch `cscript` or by explicitly calling `%windir%\SysWoW6\cscript.exe`.